# Jenkins active (exited)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jenkins, ubuntu-16.04

For some reason Jenkins stops working all the time and I have to restart jenkins service to make it work again. Every time this happens service is "**active (exited)**" but there is nothing in the logs. I use Ubuntu 16.04.

```
root@laran:~# service jenkins status
    ● jenkins.service - LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/jenkins; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: active (exited) since Sun 2017-03-05 06:09:46 EST; 6min ago
         Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
      Process: 25459 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/jenkins stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Process: 25477 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/jenkins start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Comment: Have you checked the jenkins logs at /var/log/jenkins?

Comment: @JonS I did, but there is nothing unusual. Last log is "INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running" unless there are some logs related to jobs that were executed before Jenkins stopped working.

Comment: Could you check (or post) the output of `journalctl -xu jenkins` please?

Comment: @AlexO Mar 05 07:42:15 laran jenkins[26708]: jenkins: fatal: client (pid 26709) killed by signal 9, exiting

Comment: @AlexO VPS I use only has 512MB of RAM, so maybe that's the cause?

Comment: Possibly, yes. Check output of `journalctl -b` for lines that contain `oom-killer`. If there's any, then the kernel killed your Jenkins for out of memory reasons. If there's none such line, then it's still possible that your JVM ran out of memory (e.g., not enough heap space). That should be visible from the Jenkins console output, though.

Comment: Just double-checked that the oom-killer will indeed send a SIGKILL (signal 9), so this is probably the root cause. I'll explain this in an answer to your question.

Comment: @AlexO I just checked, but there is no line containing 'oom-killed'.

Comment: It's `oom-kille*r*`...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Possibly the Linux kernel's **oom-killer** ("out-of memory killer") killed your JVM. It sends a SIGKILL signal to selected processes if the physical memory is no longer sufficient to accomodate all processes. Check that output of `journalctl` for lines containing the string `oom-killer` to confirm.

**It is normal that the oom-killer strikes only after a certain period**. Normally, Linux does not impose restrictions on the amount of virtual memory that a process requests (so your JVM can easily allocate 2 GiB of RAM on a 512 MiB system). However, if the process starts actually *using* the allocated memory (in your case: amount of used heap grows), then the kernel may find that the amount of physical memory is no longer sufficient. This is the point where the oom-killer will select a promising candiate process to be killed. Jenkins, as a non-system process that consumes a lot of memory, has very good chances to be the one that will be killed.

**You can solve the situation by**

- adding more physical memory to your system
- reducing JVM memory settings (e.g., smaller heap)

Answer (score 8):

Setting permissions for files and folders under `/var/lib/jenkins` worked for me:

```
vim /etc/sysconfig/jenkins  
# make sure that $JENKINS_USER="jenkins"

chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/lib/jenkins
chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/cache/jenkins
chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/log/jenkins
systemctl restart jenkins
```

Comment: Doing this helped me. Just to take notice: I was in a server with a user named "jenkins" that was previously created. Not sure if having created this user was the cause of the problem...

Answer (score 3):

### Have You  Updated Your Jenkins?

if So, read this...

In my case, it was a Jenkins update which changed the configuration. My custom jenkins port (9090) was changed (defaulted to 8080 after update). I was not able to open the jenkins dashboard on 9090 port. So I tried with the mentioned suggestions. I checked the `service status` and `journalctl` logs which I found absolutely misleading. The service jenkins status shows 
`Active: active (exited)` although the service is up and running.

I checked and confirmed that the jenkins jvm process was running (with `jps` command which displays list of running java processes).

So before you bang your head on figuring out what went wrong, just **check if the jenkins update has changed any configuration** and whether the jenkins process is already running in the background on some other port.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened with me.

I installed Apache first and tried installing Jenkins later. As Apache was using my localhost's port 8080, it was not allowing Jenkins to run on the same port as default port for Jenkins is also 8080.

Quick solution:

Stop Apache and try again to start Jenkins. This worked for me to change the status from Excited to Running.

I hope this might help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `journalctl` gave a very clear error:

```
Feb 01 15:21:27 localhost.localdomain polkitd[1421]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:26095:1614590 (system bus name :1.190 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path /org/freede
Feb 01 15:21:27 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Jenkins Automation Server...
Feb 01 15:21:27 localhost.localdomain runuser[26110]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user jenkins by (uid=0)
Feb 01 15:21:28 localhost.localdomain jenkins[26102]: Starting Jenkins Feb 01, 2020 3:21:27 PM Main verifyJavaVersion
Feb 01 15:21:28 localhost.localdomain jenkins[26102]: SEVERE: Running with Java class version 56 which is not in the list of supported versions: [52, 55]. Run with the --enable-future-java flag to enable such be
Feb 01 15:21:28 localhost.localdomain jenkins[26102]: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 56.0
Feb 01 15:21:28 localhost.localdomain jenkins[26102]: at Main.verifyJavaVersion(Main.java:174)
Feb 01 15:21:28 localhost.localdomain jenkins[26102]: at Main.main(Main.java:142)
Feb 01 15:21:28 localhost.localdomain jenkins[26102]: Jenkins requires Java versions [8, 11] but you are running with Java 12 from /usr/java/jdk-12.0.1
Feb 01 15:21:28 localhost.localdomain jenkins[26102]: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 56.0
Feb 01 15:21:28 localhost.localdomain jenkins[26102]: at Main.verifyJavaVersion(Main.java:174)
Feb 01 15:21:28 localhost.localdomain jenkins[26102]: at Main.main(Main.java:142)
Feb 01 15:21:28 localhost.localdomain runuser[26110]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user jenkins
Feb 01 15:21:28 localhost.localdomain jenkins[26102]: [  OK  ]
Feb 01 15:21:28 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started LSB: Jenkins Automation Server.
```

Essentially I am running with Java 12.0 which has a class file format of 56 which is not supported (yet).

This is as of `jenkins.noarch 0:2.204.2-1.1`

Answer (score 0):

The
`$JENKINS_USER="jenkins"`
should be inside:
`vim /etc/sysconfig/jenkins`

then run:

```sh
chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/log/jenkins
chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/lib/jenkins
chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/cache/jenkins
```

and restart jenkins

Answer (score 0):

**just install java first and then jenkins...this made the status from exited to running** ... order matters and not the above suggestions like permission and space...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGRiw.png)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I mistakenly deleted the log folder "/var/log/jenkins". Hence jenkins was trying to find the folder and was unable to find it and hence was not able to start.

Creating the folder again and assigning the permission to jenkins user solved my problem.

Command to assign permission to jenkins user:

chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/log/jenkins